# Django database error when checking exist email on database mongodb using djongo engine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, django-views

I made a function to check if email is exist on database, but after accessing on browser with email that already exist in database it show database error but the connection with database isn't the problem. How to solve it?

url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/check-email/?email=adrianbadjideh02@gmail.com

error:
DatabaseError at /api/check-email/

```
Request Method:GETRequest URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/check-email/?email=adrianbadjideh02@gmail.comDjango Version:4.1.9
Exception Type:DatabaseErrorException Location:C:\Users\xdead\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py, line 81, in fetchoneRaised during:UserApps.views.check_emailPython 
Executable:C:\Users\xdead\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exePython Version:3.11.3Python 
Path:[
'D:\\api_enchant', 
'C:\\Program ' 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python311.zip', 
'C:\\Program ' 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\DLLs', 
'C:\\Program ' 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\Lib', 
'C:\\Program ' 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0', 
'C:\\Users\\xdead\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\site-packages',
'C:\\Users\\xdead\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\site-packages\\win32',
'C:\\Users\\xdead\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 
'C:\\Users\\xdead\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 
'C:\\Program ' 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Pyt
```

This is my code:

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from django.http.response import JsonResponse

from UserApps.models import Users
from UserApps.serializers import UserSerializer
# Create your views here.

@csrf_exempt
def userApi(request, id=0):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        users = Users.objects.all()
        user_serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(user_serializer.data, safe=False)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        user_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=user_data)
        if user_serializer.is_valid():
            user_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Added Successfully", safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Failed to Add", safe=False)
    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        user_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        user = Users.objects.get(userid=user_data['userid'])  # Updated here
        user_serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=user_data)
        if user_serializer.is_valid():
            user_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Updated Successfully", safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Failed to Update", safe=False)
    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        user = Users.objects.get(userid=id)  # Updated here
        user.delete()
        return JsonResponse("Deleted Successfully", safe=False)


    
@csrf_exempt
def get_user(request, id):
    user = Users.objects.get(userid=id)
    user_serializer = UserSerializer(user)
    return JsonResponse(user_serializer.data, safe=False)

@csrf_exempt
def check_email(request):
    email = request.GET.get('email')  # Menggunakan request.GET untuk permintaan GET
    email_exists = Users.objects.filter(email=email).exists()
    if email_exists:
        return JsonResponse({'email_exists': email_exists})
```

```
#urls.py
from django.urls import path
from UserApps import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/user/', views.userApi),
    path('api/user/<int:id>/', views.get_user),
    path('api/check-email/', views.check_email),
]
```

if user already registered their account or when the email is already exist in database after i access this API url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/check-email/?email=adrianbadjideh02@gmail.com then it show json response like this

```
{'email_exists': email_exists}
```